# Obstacle avoidance in 2D space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, collision-detection

I am trying to create a collision check for two 2D objects in Matlab.
I have two objects, one stable (obstacle) and one moving. When they overlapse I want to get the message "error".

The problem is that although it works I think that the this approach is not easily reusable and I don't think that the "rectangle" type of object is good for what I want to do.

Any alternate ideas?

What I have done is:

```
close all;
clear all;

for i = 0 : 0.1 :  5;

aXmin = i; 
aYmin = 3.5 *sin(i);
aXmax = aXmin + 1;
aYmax = aYmin*sin(i) + 2;

set(rectangle, 'Position', [aXmin, aYmin, 1, 1]);

bXmin = 3;
bYmin = 3;
bXmax = 3.4;
bYmax = 7;

set(rectangle, 'Position', [bXmin, bYmin, 0.4, 4]);

if ((aXmin < bXmax && aXmax > bXmin) && (aYmin < bYmax && aYmax > bYmin))

display('error')
else 
display('OK')
end
pause(0.1);
end
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on your "problem" - why is the approach not reusable, why is the rectangle a poor choice?

Comment: Seems ok to me, what exactly the problem? you just don't need the lines before the loop, and the two inner brackets in the `if` condition.